# Error when trying to run blast locally

Tags: bioinformatics, fasta, blast

I am trying to run blastp locally using a multiple-fasta file as query, using this command

```
Siddharths-MacBook-Air:~ Siddharth$ blastp -db nr -query trans_mod3.txt  out results.out -remote
```

and I keep running up against this error message :

```
Critical: (110.6) CNcbiRegistry: Syntax error in system-wide configuration file: NCBI C++ Exception:
  /Users/coremake/release_build/build/PrepareRelease_IntelMAC_JSID_01_62_130.14.18.6_9056__PrepareRelease_IntelMAC_1386704300/c++/compilers/unix/../../src/corelib/ncbireg.cpp", line 630: Error: ncbi::IRWRegistry::x_Read() - Invalid registry entry format: 'users/Siddharth/blast' (m_Pos = 2)

Command line argument error: Argument "query". File is not accessible:  `trans_mod3.txt'
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. The query file is appropriately formatted, which I'm sure of because I can use it as an input on the ncbi blast page. The input file is a multiple fasta file containing about 200 sequences.

Comment: Are you sure the file `trans_mod3.txt` is located on the same path where you are executing blastp ?

Comment: Thanks. Moving the file took care of the second error. The first error message persists.

Comment: Which is the first error the one about Invalid registry entry format? did you check the `blastp -h`?